# Get dates between current date and a given month in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a table named `Stock` which contains the records of medicine stocks. It has a column named `expDate`. I want to select the stocks which are about to expire between the current date (current month) and a given month

Ex: select stocks which has the `expDate` between `4 months` from today/this month

I know that I have to write a query for this and I know how to get records between two dates. But I don't know to write a query to `get records between current date and 4 months from the current date`.

How can I do that ?

Comment: to do that you need to write sql query

Comment: @Lashane I know that i have to write a query for this and I know get records between two dates. But I don't know to write a query to get records between current date and 4 months from the current date. That's why I asked help

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: @CR7 Your comment does a better job of describing your problem than your question. Consider revising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
dbname=> create table stock ( medicine character varying ( 32 ), expDate timestamp );
CREATE TABLE
dbname=> insert into stock values ( 'first', '2015-01-01'), ('second', '2016-01-01');
INSERT 0 2
dbname=> select * from stock where expDate < now() + '4 months';
 medicine |       expdate
----------+---------------------
 first    | 2015-01-01 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

The `now()` gives the current timestamp, the `+ '4 months'` adds an interval of 4 months.